# Installing sagemath binaries in Ubuntu 20.10 flatpack chromium and jupyter notebook

Tags: chromium, 20.10, sagemath

As mentioned in other posts the sagemath package is only available in the LTE releases.The binary release 9.2 seems to work mostly. Part of the reason I'm asking my question is to document what I did to get the terminal version running.

So I downloaded sage-9.2-Ubuntu_20.04-x86_64.tar.bz2 from one of the mirrors and unpacked it into my desired directory. Running ./sage results in the following error

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘python’: No such file or directory
```

I found this simple way to get this working without a recompile:

```
sudo apt install python-is-python3
```

./sage now runs in the terminal but running

```
./sage -n jupyter
```

results in the error **Access to the file was denied** when loading `file:///home/user/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-111854-open.html`

The notebook is active if I copy & paste into firefox. Clearly this is a problem with the flatpack "jail" that chromium lives in.

Personally, I'd rather not switch my default browser for the system to firefox and I would like to accomplish the following:

1. Have a command to run the sage jupyter notebook directly in firefox or bypass the flatpack restrictions in chromium.
2. Add a sage command to my gnome launcher